# How can I use Oracle SSO SAML in Azure API Management for Authentication

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, saml, azure-api-management

Our organization uses Oracle sso saml for all application authenticarion. We are planning to move our on prem to azure paas as APIs behind API Management.

Is there any reference document to how to setup SAML based auth provider in API Management.

Thanks,
Mahesh B

Answer (score 1):

Here are some documents for your reference.

You can use Azure AD as the auth provider. [Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad).

[Single sign-on to applications in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#saml-sso).

[Oracle Cloud Infrastructure as a basic SAML single sign-on application in Azure AD](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/federatingADFSazure.htm).

Comment: You can use SAML to authenticate with Azure AD and OAuth 2.0 for API Management but you can't use SAML to authenticate with API Management,